# jQuery Add css to dynamically-added html elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I'm adding new **li** & **div** elements on a page by means of jQuery `.html()` function. The string that I pass has a hard-coded class. But it is still not stylized though the class are defined already in the css file. So I did add style by using jQuery `.css()` function, but still no style at all. How can I add css to these dynamically-added html elements?

```
for(i=0; i<directionList.length; i++) {
    html += "<li class='dir-list'> \
        <div class='dir-loc'><b>" + directionList[i].location + "</b></div><br  /> \
        <div class='dir-dest'> \
        <div class='dir-dest-icon'><img src='markers/new/transit-small.gif' class='dir-va-mid' title='by transit'/></div> \
        <div class='dir-dest-action'><span class='dir'>Ride to</span></div> \
        <div class='dir-dest-loc'><span class='dir'><b>" + directionList[i].destination + "</b></span></div> \
        <ul class='dir-routes'>";

    // add routes
    var routes = directionList[i].routes;
    for(j=0; j<routes.length; j++){
        html += "<li> \
            <div class='dir-route-type-icon'><img src='markers/new/" + routes[j].type + "-small.gif' class='dir-va-mid' title='" + routes[j].type + "'/></div> \
            <div class='dir-route-name'><span class='dir-va-mid' >" + routes[j].name + "</span></div> \
            </li>";
    }

    html += "</ul> \
        </div> \
        </li>";

    /*
    var index = parseFloat(i)+1;
    directions += "<li>" + directionList[i].location + "<span>";
    //get routes
    var routes = [];
    routes = directionList[i].routes;
    directions += "<ul>";
    for(j=0; j<routes.length; j++){
        directions += "<li>  (" + routes[j].type + ") " + routes[j].name + "</li>" ;
    }
    directions += "</ul>";
    directions +=  "</li>";
    */
}

html += "</ul>";
$('#directions').html(html);
```

CSS:

```
#directions div { 
    display:inline; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#directions ul#dir { 
    list-style:decimal;
}
#directions ul.dir-routes { 
    list-style: none;
}

.dir-va-mid {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Adding the CSS by force:

```
$("#directions div").css({'display':'inline', 'vertical-align':'middle'});
$("#directions ul#dir").css({'list-style':'decimal'});
$("#directions ul.dir-routes").css({'list-style':'none'});
$(".dir-va-mid").css({'vertical-align':'middle'});
```

**Edit**: I had included my files [**here**](http://cid-d8e339d08dd4d02c.office.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public/problem?uc=3). Please look at it if you have the time.

Comment: Please post some code. It sounds like the elements your adding via jQuery simply aren't matching your existing CSS selectors.

Comment: the concept of "some" code isn't clear to everyone it seems :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having a problem with [CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

**Purely as a test** to see if this is indeed your problem, you should remove your jQuery `.css()` lines, and add `!important` to each declaration in your CSS, like this:

```
#directions div { 
    display: inline !important; 
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
#directions ul#dir { list-style: decimal !important;}
#directions ul.dir-routes { list-style: none !important;}

.dir-va-mid {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

If this works, then you **need to show more of the surrounding HTML**, so we can give you a **proper solution** which will properly take advantage of the rules of specificity.

**You shouldn't use `!important`** to band-aid problems unless there is no other way.

If it still doesn't work, then there is some other problem, and you probably need to show us more of your code anyway.

---

I can't recreate your problem with the files you posted, because lots of files are missing.

However, I did notice one thing **inside your CSS file** which isn't right:

```
<![if lt IE 7]>
* html #outer{
    width:100%;/* box model hack for ie5.+*/
}
<![endif]>
```

You should change that to this:

```
* html #outer{
    width:100%;/* box model hack for ie5.+*/
}
```

- Conditional comments are not valid inside a CSS file.
- You're using the [Star HTML hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_HTML_hack), which by definition will only apply styles to IE less than 7.

See if anything has changed after fixing this.